# Why does as.formula('x') result in a stack usage error?

Tags: r

If I run

```
as.formula('x')
```

I get

```
Error: C stack usage [some large number] is too close to the limit
```

If I do

```
as.formula('y')
```

The error is

```
obejct 'y' not found
```

If I define both `x` and `y` as numbers, I get the same error for `'x'`, but I get an `invalid formula` error for `'y'`, which is what I expect.

Obviously I would not want to code either of these for practical use, but I thought the error with `'x'` was kind of esoteric and inconsistent.

Does anyone know why there is a difference here?

Comment: (I'm inferring R < 4.0, as this does not fail in R-4.0.2.) The formal arguments for `as.formula` include `x=`. Since formulas often suggest model matrices, or perhaps delayed evaluation of mathematical expressions, by avoiding the tilde in your formula (I don't think you're using it right, btw), it seems to be that when processing your `'x'`, it confuses that with its own argument name, `as.formula(x=)`. This is why `'y'` fails differently: `y=` is not an argument, so it does not get confused.

Comment: Did you try this on a fresh R session?

Comment: This was on a fresh R session I got thhe error using an R interpreter on a Linux server, and the same error on RStudio on a Linux machine.

Comment: I seem to get the same error from `formula('x')` vs. `formula('y')` as well, which seems to be the last point where I can trace anything. I don't know of any other functions in R that behave this way.